# Migrating from H2 to mysql - wso2 apimanager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a working instance of wso2-apimanager 1.6 with its default database.
Since will be deploying wso2 in cluster I intend to use a MySQL database.

Once I start using MySQL how do get my previous data on this DB i.e my users, user applications, subscriptions etc.??

Or will I have to start over fresh??

Comment: Thanks @abimaran! The wso2-am tag was missing on stackoverflow. Was added recently I guess.

Comment: Yes, I created it recently. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For production deployments, we always recommend to use a production-ready database. So, that questions like yours can be avoided.

H2 is provided as anyone can just download and run it.

You can create tables in MySQL from the given scripts and look for a way to migrate data from H2 to MySQL.

I hope this is clear.